# Prevent or Counter Running Grapples?

Tags: wwe-13

It seems that the way most people "play" online matches is to spam running grapples.  Is there any defense against this?  If so, is there any super star or move that makes it easier to block / counter running grapples?  This is just about ruining the WWE 13 online experience for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good tips in this [site](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672340-wwe-13/64486978), specially in the ninth post. Basically, it's all about timing your counter attack, instead of trying to hit your opponent back mindlessly.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try a running grapple with the CPU? Most of times they put you on the ground. Want to do the same? Wait for your opponent run at you, and when he tries to grapple you, press `A`. It's very useful, and better than trying to reverse or something like that.

Comment: Due to server lag the timing is very difficult and more often than not the person running will get their shot landed anyway =/

Answer (score -1):

Hold down L2 when you press the reversal button (R2). It makes it easier to counter attacks when timed correctly.